# MYSQL and condition not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the code to get the mysql_num_rows() but always giving the output Zero

```
$myc= "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user_id=$userid AND quiz_id=$myqid";
$completed=mysql_query($myc,$kpsctuts->connect) or  die('MySql Error!  ' . mysql_error());
echo "<br/> row count:  ".mysql_num_rows($completed);
if (mysql_num_rows($completed) > 0) {
exit;
}
```

Comment: `mysql_query($myc,$kpsctuts->connect)` ? Procedural `mysql_query` with an OOP-type connection? Means you're probably mixing the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` libraries

Comment: @CD001 Doens't necessarly means OP's mixing 2 drivers. He could've written his own class, altough I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Daan - true, could also be PDO in OOP style ... I was just aiming for the most likely culprit ;) And the comment was still new enough to edit so .. :P

Comment: its calling from class, the DB connection is working  working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method to get the data from mysql server.

```
$connect=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$connect);

$myc= "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user_id=$userid AND quiz_id=$myqid";
$completed=mysql_query($myc);
echo mysql_error();

echo "<br/> row count:  ".mysql_num_rows($completed);
if (mysql_num_rows($completed) > 0) {
exit;
}
```

This is only based on mysql_query which helps to establish connection before executing the query

Comment: @Gunasegar Please note, the mysql library is highly deprecated! You should use mysqli or PDO. Have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) where it's stated for everyone to see!

Comment: @Raj Welcome. Raphael Muller will try to look into PDO or mysqli.